# Vapor / liquid balance in a closed container?

Tags: vapor-pressure

How is the vapor-liquid balance in a closed container computed as a function of temperature? In other words, if I have a container half full of water and I heat the container from 20-degrees C to 30-degrees C, then how would that affect the amount of water vapor in the container?

I know there is the equation PV=nRT, where "n" is the amount of something, but I am not sure how to use this equation to compute the amount of vapor as a function of temperature. For example, if T goes up and V remains the same, then obviously P will go up also, but the n I guess refers to the total amount of water vapor in the container (assuming no air is present) which, what?, stays the same?

Comment: Search for water vapor tension (partial pressure of saturated water vapor) as function of temperature. There are many data in form of tables, charts or empirical equations.

Comment: @Poutnik Those tell me the PRESSURE of the vapor, not how much vapor there is (molar quantity).

Comment: But that is with negligible error idealized as $n = \dfrac{pV}{RT}$

Answer (score 2):

Say you have an initial amount of water $n$ in a closed container at pressure $p_1$ and temperature $T_1$. The closed container has a volume $V$. We know that the *final* state is at vapour-liquid equilibrium.

---

You give some heat $Q$ so that the temperature increases to $T_2$. The energy balance disregarding kinetic energy, potential energy, and any work done is simply

$$ Q = \Delta U \rightarrow \boxed{U_2^\mathrm{sat}(T_2) = Q + U_1(p_1,T_1)} \tag{1} $$

Note that Eq. (1) gives us the value of the final internal energy. Since the final state is a VLE equilibrium, its thermodynamic properties depend *only* on one intensive variable. One way to apply this abstract equation is to go to the water tables. Once you know $p_1$ and $T_1$ read the value of $U_1(p_1,T_1)$ in $\pu{kJ/kg}$ or any other unit. Then, sum to that value $Q$. Finally, go the the saturated part of the table to identify where $U_2$ is located, and you should also read $T_2$.

The volume of the container cannot change. Let $v$ be the molar volume, then

$$ V = n^\mathrm{vap} v_2^\mathrm{vap}(T_2) + 
       n^\mathrm{liq} v_2^\mathrm{liq}(T_2) \tag{2} $$
Since you know $T_2$, you can also locate the saturated liquid and vapour molar volumes in the table. Another obvious equation comes from the conservation of the amount of substance
$$ n = n^\mathrm{vap} + n^\mathrm{liq} \tag{3} $$

Eqs. (2) and (3) form a set of two equations with two unknowns, $n^\mathrm{vap}$ and $n^\mathrm{liq}$, which are the ones you are interested in finding.

You can repeat this procedure for several $Q$'s given, so that you end up at higher temperatures. Repeat the procedure and plot the amounts $n^\mathrm{vap}$ and $n^\mathrm{liq}$ as a function of the final temperature $T_2$.